# Alt + Tab suddenly stopped working properly

Tags: gnome, window, application-switcher

Normally, holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through windows. However, suddenly, holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> brings up the window switcher like normal, but further presses of Tab do nothing; it doesn't cycle through the open windows.

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting the shell seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can Install CompizConfig-Settings-Manager by terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Or search for it in Ubuntu software center

After installing, open it, scroll down and search for **Windows Management**

Mark the Check box: **Application Switcher**

Comment: Application switcher is already enabled and part of the Unity settings. According to the user it was something else, one of those "unknowns" that disapear with a... Rebot :)